# Unable to get EPPROM size

Tags: smartcard

I have acos3 card and acr38 with part number acr38u-spc-r and I am trying to get EPPROM size and I am using the following command

> 80 14 05 00 00

the response i am getting

> 91 00

How can I get EEPROM size??

In the documentation it says I should get

> 90 xx

where xx is EEPROM size in hexadecimal

The sdk tool used the same command and it returned the same response, however it translated this result to card EEPROM size is 256kb, how did it achieve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only logical answer i can think of is the documentation is wrong.

So either i am getting 9 as a response for success and the next three zeros for the size of EEPROM Or because this is card is 256 it requires 3 digits and since it couldn’t find space, it overlapped on the next digit. 
So it’s either overlapping or mistake in the reference manual for this size of a card, since no one can give me a definite answer.

The cause of all this mess is that there are certain commands that return the same value 91 00  also as a success response